# Open link from popup.html in new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I add a link from `popup.js` to `popup.html` - it is added correctly, clickable - but new tab with it doesn't open.

**Popup.js**

```
var views = chrome.extension.getViews({ type: "popup" });
views[0].document.getElementById("content").innerHTML =
             '<a href="https://www.google.com">Link</a>';
```

**Popup.html**

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

What can be done to open the link in new tab?

I've tried another approach - but with it i even don't got a link into popup:

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
   var y = document.getElementById("content");
   y.addEventListener("click", openIndex);
   console.log(y);
});

function openIndex() {
 chrome.tabs.create({active: true, url: "https://www.google.com"});
};
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why not use `target="_blank"` as usual in every website?

Comment: Because i need to create an url in `popup.js` from two variables and pass it to `popup.html` - thats why i can't just use `<a href...` target="_blank">anchor</a>" in `popup.html`. I tried another approach - but still without succeess - it is in updated post.

Comment: I don't understand that. In the given `popup.js`, you have a block of markup. That contains `<a href = "$url">Link</a>` - why not add `target="_blank"` there?

Comment: Got your point - yes it works!!! Thank you!